Is there any way that I can access to the header origin in Pre Authentication with Lambda?
I am trying to secure the User Pool ID by limit the domain can access to my User Pool.
If someone has my Pool ID and try to make a fake site with it, they can not make sign in/sign up to my User Pool
I have tried to research in AWS Docs but can not find an answer.
The solution I am making is create a Lambda trigger when user sign in/sign up to check their header origin but I don't know how to access this or Lambda event doesn't support this feature

Please provide more details, its not clear what you the problem is
